# Cannot use a Tablelayout within a widget?

Tags: android, widget, tablelayout

Here is the xml file of my Android widget:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TableLayout 
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="1">
        <TableRow>
            <!-- Some views -->
        </TableRow>
    
        <TableRow>
            <!-- Some views -->
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

(full code here: http://pastebin.com/Kqxs5t9E)

This code is showing me some good results in Eclipse, but as soon as I sent the file to my device and try to add the widget to my homescreen I get this error code and the widget showing: "Problem Loading the Widget":

```
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860): updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, using error view
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.widget.TableLayout
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:930)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetHostView.java:219)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetHostView.java:155)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost.createView(AppWidgetHost.java:218)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at com.fede.launcher.Launcher.bindAppWidgets(Launcher.java:3652)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at com.fede.launcher.Launcher.access$22(Launcher.java:3639)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at com.fede.launcher.Launcher$DesktopBinder.handleMessage(Launcher.java:4625)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Class not allowed to be inflated android.widget.TableLayout
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.failNotAllowed(LayoutInflater.java:525)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:472)
08-01 22:11:26.917: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(5860):     ... 20 more
```

So what? I cannot use a Tablelayout within a widget????

What is the best solution so? I can create a lot of relativelayout but I guess that's not a good idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I cannot use a Tablelayout within a
>   widget????

If by "widget" you mean "app widget", then, no, you cannot use a `TableLayout` in an app widget. [There are only a few widgets that can be used in an app widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout).

> I can create a lot of relativelayout
>   but I guess that's not a good idea.

I do not know why you think `RelativeLayout` is bad. You may be able to replace your `LinearLayout`, `TableLayout`, and `TableRow` widgets with a single `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: I think I was too tired after hours of coding. This question seem now so stupid.

Thank a lot for the kind answer