# Android: How to add a dynamic table layout to the widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

i have a initial layout loaded properly.

now that i want to add contents to the widget. they are retrieved from a webservice.

hence i am using table layout which i created in updateService method inside appwidget provider.

how to add this table layout into the widget? remoteview did not help :(

Comment: Do you have a widget that is on the home screen that you want to fill automatically?

Comment: yes. i have the widget on the home screen. there are so many contents which i wanted to add but in a good way.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate issue
[cannot use a Tablelayout within a widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383596/cannot-use-a-tablelayout-within-a-widget)

Table Layout inside a 'Widget' isn't possible.
'RelativeLayout' is the way to go.

App Widget can only use a limited set of Widgets.
More here... http://android.bigresource.com/Track/android-zjmeISGMz/